# matlab code to java translation for monte carlo simulation

Tags: java, matlab, montecarlo

I'm trying to code a monte carlo simulation to java from MATLAB code.  The MATLAB answer does not match the answer of the java code.  I should be getting about 34% but instead get 29%, other variations of the problem I'm trying to solve result in a -5% difference from what I suppose to get. Did I coded something wrong? or is the Random class in java not random enough for a monte carlo sim?

MATLAB CODE:

```
01 meetings = 0;
02 for loop = 1:1000000
03     L = 30*rand;
04     B = 30*rand;
05     if B<L & L<B+7
06        meetings = meetings +1;
07     elseif L<B & L>B-5
08        meetings = meetings +1;
09     end
10 end
11 meetings/1000000
```

java code:

```
import java.util.Random;

public class Malt {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        double meetings = 0;
        int l = 0, b = 0;
        Random random = new Random();

        for(int i = 1; i < 1000000; i++){
            l = (int) (random.nextDouble()*30);
            b = (int) (random.nextDouble()*30);
            if((b<l)&&(l<(b+7)))
                meetings = meetings +1;
            else if((l<b)&&(l>(b-5)))
                meetings = meetings +1;
        }
        System.out.println(meetings/1000000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are these aggregated results or results from single runs of each implementation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the casts to (int). That automatically rounds your results down. If those are removed, you have an exact equivalent to your MATLAB program and get similar results (I'm getting ~35.8%). Try changing your `l` and `b` to `double` values and removing the `(int)` casts from the random assignment.

Of course, if your intention is to floor, then you need to edit your MATLAB code too and it will probably also give you ~29%.

Also, if you are worried about the reliability of `Random` (which seems to work fine here), you might try `SecureRandom`, which is slower but less deterministic.